# Hiding quiz button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a form divided into 5 parts, like a questionnaire. At the end of each question, there is a button to go to the next one, however, I need the button to only appear if the user types at least 3 characters in the input field. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```html
  <input required type="text" name="idade_aluno_lp" id="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var count = document.getElementById('idade_aluno_lp');
  if (count.length < 3) {
    document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>

<div class="text-end mt-3">
  <div id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar Resposta</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use it in a form and put the hiding code in onsubmit.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns the actual element. So try accessing the value attribute: `count.value.length` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Little snippet with the fix:

```html
<input required type="text" name="idade_aluno_lp" id="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno" onkeyup="check()" />

<div class="text-end mt-3">
  <input type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function check() {
    var count = document.getElementById('idade_aluno_lp');
    if (count.value.length < 3) {
      document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, if I don't type anything, and press ENTER, it skips to the next question, so I changed from onkeyup="check()" to onkeypress="return check(event)", and to accept only numbers, I added on check(): var key = event.keyCode and if (key >= 48 && key <= 57). But now I have two problems: 1) When I press backspace (←) to remove the numbers from the input, the button doesn't disappear. 2) If I delete a value, and choose a previously filled value that was in the browser's cache, the button doesn't appear. It might be better to continue using onkeyup. Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I think adding onchange(check(event)) might fix your issue with autofill. For the backspace, I guess there is something wrong in the changes you made.